# Filtering association model in active admin and Act Taggable On

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, acts-as-taggable-on

A has many B. I used Act Taggable On gem in the two models. This gem creates a intermediate table called taggings. The tags are saved in table tag and the relation between A, or B, with the tags in the table taggings. Thus, the type of tags are A or B and that information is saved in a column called taggable_type of the table taggings. I need to know if it possible to create a filter (not custom filter) in the page of A where it is possible to filtering by all tags. For example Suposse a1 is a object of A, and b1 and b2 is a object of B. b1 and b2 have a tag "tags_B". Then when I filter by tags1 in page of A I need to show a1.

There is any way to make this using the sintax of active admin?

I trying

admin/A

```
filter: A_or_B_tags_name_taggings
```

But that doesnot work

Comment: Is this to show the existing tags of an "owner" ?

Comment: no, it is not @bkunzi01